# ¿Cómo puedo evitar error A cross-origin error was thrown en login?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs

Estoy trabajando un proyecto en React que tiene un login, el cuál está conectado con un backend de nodejs que consume los datos desde MongoDB. Si ingreso datos correctos que estén registrados en la base de datos no se presenta ningún error y el usuario se puede loguear correctamente, pero si los datos son incorrectos o el campo de usuario o contraseña están vacíos me genera el siguiente error.

[image: Error generado]

En la consola me muestra que se está tratando de recorrer un **JSON** vacío como respuesta del servidor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahí creo que se puede estar generando el error, y al mostrar los datos que me está regresando el json es **undefined**. Del lado del frontend este es el código que se encarga de procesar el logueo.

```
import decode from 'jwt-decode';

export default class AuthService{

    constructor(domain){
        this.domain = domain || "http://localhost:3000/api";
        this.requestFetch = this.requestFetch.bind(this);
        this.login = this.login.bind(this);
        this.logout = this.logout.bind(this);
        this.getProfile = this.getProfile.bind(this);
    }

    login(Usuario,Password){
        return this.requestFetch('/usuario/login',{
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({Usuario,Password})
        }).then(response=>{
            this.setToken(response.tokenReturn);
            this.setUser(response.user);
            return Promise.resolve(response);
        });
    }

    isLoggedIn(){
        return !!this.getToken();
    }

    setToken(token){
        localStorage.setItem('token_id',token);
    }

    getToken(){
        return localStorage.getItem('token_id');
    }

    setUser(userJSON){
        localStorage.setItem('user',JSON.stringify(userJSON));
    }



    getUser(){
       return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')); 
    }

    getUserAccess(){
        let user = this.getUser();
        if(user){
            return user.Rol;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    getProfile(){
        return decode(this.getToken());
    }

    logout(){
        localStorage.removeItem('token_id');
        localStorage.removeItem('user');
    }

    requestFetch(urlRelative,options){
        const headers = {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }

        if(this.isLoggedIn()){
            headers['token'] = this.getToken();
        }

        return fetch(this.domain+ urlRelative,{
            headers,
            ...options
        }).then(response=>response.json()).catch(
            error=> Promise.reject(error)
        )
    }

}
```

Y en el Backend este es el código que se encarga de procesar la petición y regresar la respuesta. Cuando el usuario está registrado regresa todos los datos que existen de ese usuario en la base de datos, cuando el usuario no existe regresa un **404**.

```
login: async (req,res,next) => {
        try {

            let user = await models.findOne({Usuario: req.body.Usuario});
            console.log(req.body.Usuario);
            if (user){
                let match = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.Password,user.Password);
                if (match){
                    let tokenReturn = await token.encode(user._id);
                    res.status(200).json({user,tokenReturn});
                } else{
                    res.status(404).send({
                        message: 'Password Incorrecto'
                    });
                }
            } else{
                res.status(404).send({
                    message: 'No existe el usuario'
                });
            }
        } catch(e){
            res.status(500).send({
                message:'Ocurrió un error'
            });
            next(e);
        }
    }
```

Intente crear un condicional que ejecute **getUser** si la respuesta es diferente a undefined, pero el logueo deja de funcionar y siempre permite ingresar a los usuarios sin importar si está o no registrado.

Comment: Necesitas usar [cors](https://npmjs.com/package/cors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La corrección debe ser en el backend, debes usar un middleware para activar el cors

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// esto es lo que debes agregar
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```